# What is the proper way to std::byteswap member bitfields in C++

Tags: c++, deserialization, endianness, bit-fields, c++23

I need to convert struct fields that came via network as raw bytes from big-endian to little-endian.

Consider the following struct:

```cpp
struct [[gnu::packed]] Header {
    std::uint8_t magic_value:4;
    std::uint8_t offset:4;
    std::uint8_t flag1:1;
    std::uint8_t flag2:1;
    std::uint8_t flag3:1;
    std::uint8_t flag4:1;
    std::uint8_t flag5:1;
    std::uint8_t flag6:1;
    std::uint8_t flag7:1;
    std::uint8_t flag8:1;
};
```

What is the proper way to convert deserialized big-endian `Header` to little-endian `Header`?

Comment: Looks like a series of `uint8_t`, the compiler will keep those bytes as is. Just like you don't byte swap strings. Unless you aliased/type punted that structure into some other int types somewhere

Comment: The `[[gnu::packed]]` part suggests that both sides are compiled with GCC? Member bitfield order is _not_ defined in C++. It's quite possible that no action is needed at all.

Comment: A `uint8_t` is just a single byte, so has no byte order. Bitfields *do* have a bitorder though, and that is unspecified. It is known that gcc and MSVC disagree on which bit of the byte to store `flag1` in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).

```
const auto big_endian_data = std::bit_cast<std::uint16_t>(input);
const auto small_endian_data = std::byteswap(big_endian_data);
auto header = std::bit_cast<Header>(small_endian_data);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a valid option, however if I have a `HeaderAnother`, s.t. `sizeof(HeaderAnother) > 8` : I'm starting to experience some difficulties with `std::bit_cast` of `HeaderAnother`?

Comment: @blonded04 how do you pack/send those structs? Do you just memcpy them into a byte buffer and then send? Or do you store them in an array of some other type of int? Are you sure that you need to byteswap in your case?

Comment: @PeterT yes, I copy them from byte buffer and then try to work with them;

I'm on my way to simply get rid of flag1-flag8 and make it into 1 uint8_t field `flags` -- sounds like the easiest workaround

Comment: This might work by accident (bitfield layouts aren't portable) but in general, endian-ness only changes the order of bytes in primitive types (`int`, `short`, `long` etc) and not in classes.